# Absolute positioned element and responsive design

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm doing the responsive part of a template, and I'm facing an issue with an absolutely positioned element. When resizing the screen, the absolutely positioned element starts to move from its position, which is unwanted. It is possible to just use media queries, but then I would need to use them for almost each pixel the element moves(or maybe I'm incorrect?).

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/QMdMXo

```
 #design {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: green;
  min-height: 850px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative; }

  #design #big {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; }

  #design #small {
    position: absolute;
    right: 655px;
    top: 300px; }
```

Comment: I looked at your CSS code on the Code Pen, you know you can apply styles to all elements with the `*` selector, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use % instead of pixel   eg: for right positon

```
 #design #small {
   position: absolute;
   right: 38%;
   top: 300px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you want to put that element because you didn't specify it in your question but if you want to put that element somewhere without changing it's position use `position: relative` and choose the position accordingly.